# Flutter How to Implement the UMP SDK

Tags: android, flutter

I am using Flutter with google_mobile_ads package for my free app. As the app publisher who uses Admob, I need to Implement the UMP SDK to comply with the requirement to use a Google-certified Consent Management Platform (CMP).

I need to update my app code to comply.

Google says ask user consent for:

1. Cookies and analytics
2. personalized vs non-personalized ads

Consent is required if:

1. a user is located in the EU or UK
2. a user is located in the EU or UK and the user is under age 18

Implementation Steps:

1. if the user is not in the EU or UK, then no consent form on app launch is needed
2. if the user is in the EU or UK, then show consent form(for cookies and analytics and using personalized ads vs non-personalized ads). In this case, the user cannot proceed without accepting the consent form.
3. if the user is in the EU or UK and under age 18, then show consent form(cookies and analytics and using personalized ads vs non-personalized ads). In this case, the user cannot proceed without accepting the consent form.

There are 4 questions:

1. google ads are all use cookies for analytics. This question answer should always be yes otherwise, the consent will be declined, and the app should not launch. Do you agree?
2. How do we determine the user location using the code?
3. How do we determine the user age?
4. Users have no control whether they are using personalized ads vs non-personalized ads b/c this is based on the admob account setting for the app. I don't think there is a way to check admob setting using the code.

There are [instructions](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/ump/android/quick-start) how to implement UMP SDK in Java/Kotlin

There is the package: user_messaging_platform (16 months old)

We could create plugin(to use Kotlin in Flutter) - please see question here: stackoverflow.com/questions/76815370/using-kotlin-code-in-flutter-via-methodchannel

Creating such plugin is too complex.

Another option is to create Flutter package(Dart only code) specifically to address this compliance issue which I feel is too complex.

We need to do the following:
[image]

We could also pick an option in the Admob account, but we still neeed to do the above steps:

[image]

Please provide your thoughts.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Google eventually integrated it into the ad plugin and documented it at: https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/flutter/eu-consent

Update: to show you how I did it. It only relies on the current `google_mobile_ads` package, nothing else. It's built as a `ChangeNotifier` in order to inject it into my app as a `Provider` but it would work with any other state management solution as well.

```dart
class ConsentManager with ChangeNotifier {
  ConsentStatus? status;

  bool get hasConsent => status == ConsentStatus.obtained || status == ConsentStatus.notRequired;

  ConsentManager() {
    ConsentInformation.instance.getConsentStatus().then((status) {
      status = status;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  void updateConsent() {
    final params = ConsentRequestParameters(
      tagForUnderAgeOfConsent: false,
      consentDebugSettings: ConsentDebugSettings(
        debugGeography: DebugGeography.debugGeographyDisabled,
      ),
    );
    ConsentInformation.instance.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
      params,
      () async {
        if (await ConsentInformation.instance.isConsentFormAvailable()) _loadForm();
      },
      (FormError error) {},
    );
  }

  void _loadForm() {
    ConsentForm.loadConsentForm(
      (consentForm) async {
        status = await ConsentInformation.instance.getConsentStatus();
        if (status == ConsentStatus.required) {
          consentForm.show(
            (formError) => _loadForm(),
          );
        }
      },
      (formError) {},
    );
  }

  Future<void> debugReset() async {
    await ConsentInformation.instance.reset();
  }
}
```

And this is how you could use it from your app (provided you inject it somehow, as a `Provider`, with `ListenableBuilder`, with an `InheritedNotifier`, using Riverpod or anything else):

```dart
ConsentManager consenting;

if (!consenting.hasConsent) {
  //consenting.debugReset();
  consenting.updateConsent();
}
```

(You could also call the code directly from your app, of course, I happen to prefer this approach to outsource anything like this into a separate manager.)

As of today (5 Dec, 2023), it doesn't work as Rashid describes. Yes, that would be the logical approach, non-consenting users getting non-personalized ads, consenting users getting personalized ones. Unfortunately, that's not the case. Consenting users keep getting ads while non-consenting users are put into a so-called "limited ads" mode that means (as acknowledged by Google in [documentation*](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy/gdpr#frequently_asked_questions)) no ad from AdMob, maybe waterfall from others if you use mediation.

Besides, you have two options with the consent dialog. Two buttons, either *Don't consent/Consent*, with the result above, or *Manage Options/Consent* where *Manage Options* leads to a very long and very complicated settings screen that will put the average user off. And, even more, if you just go into *Manage Options*, touch nothing but *Confirm*, you get the same no-ads-at-all-mode automatically.

---

* "What happens if I implement a CMP and users don't consent?

Limited Ads serving applies if there is no consent for IAB TCF Purpose 1 in accordance with the EU user consent policy. Per the Limited Ads "Demand Eligibility" section, the initial offering in limited ads is just waterfall mediation, meaning no ads are returned from the AdMob network."

Comment: Hello! I don't see any sign that Google integrated the UMP SDK into the Google Mobile Ads plugin(pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads). The Google Ads example code only addresses different ad types. The link attached talks about how to implement UMP SDK, but I don't see any solution.

Comment: `ConsentStatus`, `ConsentInformation` and all the related types are present in `google_mobile_ads`. I don't know since when but they certainly are there in the current 3.1.0. You can set up the consent dialog without using any other package, directly from Flutter. But, and this is a humongous but, you'll experience the very same issues that lots of people are complaining about and there seems to be absolutely no intention from Google to provide any solution or guidance, at least not for now: if your users simply say Don't Consent, your app will become free to use, no ads will be shown at all.

Comment: As of now, nobody seems to know what will come in January, whether Google really kills the freemium, ad-based app model completely or not. And those who might know won't utter a word. People in the AdMob support list contemplate various solutions, disabling some (all?) app functionality for non-consenting users, switching ad providers, or both. Rough times lie ahead of us, for sure.

Comment: you are calling `consenting.hasConsent` before variable `consenting` has been initialized. the constructor of `ConsentManager` also contains an async code which `hasConsent`'s results relies on. no?

Comment: No, I'm not. This was just a small extract of how to use it generally, in my own code, `consenting` is an injected dependency using a provider that's very well defined by the time it gets there (I specifically mentioned this fact, actually). I guess that developers at the level of needing the consent framework are already pass the stage when they try to use uninitialized variables without remarking. :-) I'm still more worried about the crux of the matter, though. Google actually made a small announcement of doing something lately.

Comment: @Gábor I am always getting `ConsentStatus.unknown` as result of `getConsentStatus()`. According to Google, you need to register with a CMP provider or sth like that in order for the relevant form to be shown. Is that assumed and not mentioned here? Or is it not necessary at all despite Google mentioning it is?

Comment: I have an app in the store with this solution and I'm not aware of any problems (which doesn't mean there couldn't be any :-) ). No specific registration.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can implement UMP consent with package google_mobile_ads ver 3.1.0. Check this link from google
[EU Consent for Flutetr](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/eu-consent)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I test like that

```
 ConsentDebugSettings debugSettings = ConsentDebugSettings(
      debugGeography: DebugGeography.debugGeographyEea,
      testIdentifiers: ['my id']);



  void loadForm() {
    ConsentForm.loadConsentForm(
          (ConsentForm consentForm) async {
        // Present the form


      },
          (FormError formError) {

      },
    );
  }


  final params = ConsentRequestParameters(
      consentDebugSettings: debugSettings);

  ConsentInformation.instance.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
    params,
        () async {
      if (await ConsentInformation.instance.isConsentFormAvailable()) {
        loadForm();
      }
    },
        (FormError error) {
      // Handle the error
    },
  );
```

but not pop up consent is display. I have well create a grpd consent form on admob

Answer (score 0):

> 1. google ads are all use cookies for analytics. This question answer should always be yes otherwise, the consent will be declined, and the
>    app should not launch. Do you agree?

**Answer:**
The UMP SDK handle your consent for your automatically. If your users denied the consent, it will serve non-personalized ads but most likely you will get a no fill error due to no ad inventory for non personalize ads.

> 2. How do we determine the user location using the code or we ask the user a question whether a user is located in the EU or UK?

**Answer:**
UMP SDK also handles this for you. You will just need to do the following:
Request consent information: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy#request-consent
Load and show consent form if required: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy#load-and-show-form

> How do we determine the user age or we ask the user to a question
> whether a user age is under 18?

**Answer:**
As mentioned, UMP SDK handles this for you. However, if you app is for children, you will also need to comply with Children's Online Privacy Protection Act (COPPA). For this, you will need to follow Child-directed settings: https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/targeting#child-directed_setting

> 1. Users have no control whether they are using personalized ads vs non-personalized ads b/c this is based on the admob account setting
>    for the app. I don't think there is a way to check admob setting using
>    the code. Is this correct?

**Answer:**
Yes, you're correct. If your users don't consent to your app, then AdMob will served non-personalized ads. Otherwise, it will served personalized ads

> 1. How do we Implement the UMP SDK using Flutter?

**Answer:**
Unfortunately, there's no direct implementation of the UMP SDK via Flutter. For this, you will need to export your flutter project into a Native platform (Android or IOS), then follow the UMP SDK installation for that specific platform. You may check the UMP SDK implementation below:

```
iOS : https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy#prerequisites
Android: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy#prerequisites
```